# What life forms would appear around decaying animal carcasses in a temperate, rocky desert?

Tags: ecology

My biome is a rocky mountain in a temperate climate. There is little-to-no soil, and little growing except scraps of grass, moss, and maybe some shrubs.

However birds frequently die in a certain area, and their rotting bodies can provide nourishment for plants and insects. This process has been going on for decades, not centuries.

What kinds of life forms would I expect to find?

Comment: google desert scavengers

Comment: @john's right. -1 for lack of research. Please google desert scavengers then ask us specific questions if that doesn't answer your question (be prepared to explain why it didn't answer your question). Prior research is an expectation on Stack Exchange, which is expected to be the *last* place you seek an answer. Not the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering about the sort of animal types that may live in this environment, I would probably expect to find smaller reptilians, and possibly a larger species that can hunt and scavenge, similar to a dingo or coyote. I believe reptiles would be a good choice of scavenger due to their cold-blooded nature and, for many desert species such as the spiny lizard and the horned lizard, their ability to go on for long lengths of time without need for water. Small reptiles also need places to hide during the day, both from predators and the sun. Since this is a rocky mountain, they would have many, many different places to hide and rest in. You also mentioned that most of the carcasses are from birds, meaning avian species are also common in this environment. With this knowledge, a vulture-like species could thrive in this type of biome, as long as the carcasses are large or plenty enough for them to live off of. All in all, I would recommend doing some research on scavenger species in the real world to make your species seem more believable, but I hope I was of some help to you!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer scavengers.  The main source of food Appears to be dead animals ( Where these birds come from why they die is something you need to flush out)  So the only animals that are likely to last in this environment or those that feed on the meat of these dead birds. So you'd expect scavengers or omnivores with strong stomachs that can Digest rotten meat.